# Unable to use JSON array for Azure Function

Tags: c#, json.net, azure-functions, json-deserialization, jsonparser

I have below JSON input for My azure function but unable to pass it in after deserialize object

```
{
  "name": [{
      "SiteName": "Site1",
      "SiteUrl": "https://site1.com/"
    },
    {
      "SiteName": "Site2",
      "SiteUrl": "https://site2.com/"
    },
  ]
}
```

after deserialize I am getting count as 2 but inside array value I am not getting for deserializing using below code

```
string requestBody = new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEnd();
dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
       
var Root = data["name"].ToObject<List<Constant>>();
```

and for Constant class declared like below

```
class Constant
{
     public Dictionary<string, string> name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to create class like below.

```
class JsonResponse
{
    public List<Constant> name { get; set; }
}

class Constant
{
    public string SiteName { get; set; }
    public string SiteUrl { get; set; }
}
```

And try to Deserialize response with `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonResponse>(requestBody)`.

```
string requestBody = new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEnd();
JsonResponse data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonResponse>(requestBody);
var Root = data.name;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1: Deserialize as object list**

The model class should be:

```cs
public class Site
{
    public string SiteName { get; set; }
    public string SiteUrl { get; set; }
}
```

And deserialize as below:

```cs
var Root = data["name"].ToObject<List<Site>>();
```

[Sample program (Site class)](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jhwhqC)

---

**Solution 2: Deserialize as Dictionary**

```cs
var Root = data["name"].ToObject<List<Dictionary<string, string>>>();
```

[Sample program (Dictionary)](https://dotnetfiddle.net/57ab95)